# Can't Install Openvas on Kali

Tags: kali-linux, redis

I've can't solve this problem. Trying to install Openvas on Kali. I'm surprised by the amount of problems I'm facing to install a program on this OS.

I've used

```
apt-get install openvas
```

Done. Then I used

```
openvas-check-setup
```

Getting this error:

```
ERROR: redis-server is not running or not listening on socket: /tmp/redis.sock
FIX: You should start the redis-server or configure it to listen on socket: /tmp/redis.sock
```

I don't have a redis.sock on tmp folder. I tried to fix it by everything I found online.

Answer (score 2):

I encountered the same issue. The problem is that OpenVas is looking for Redis Socket in /tmp
We need to change this location in OpenVas by editing the file /etc/openvas/openvassd.conf

The problem that in Kali Linux, OpenVas does not have file: /etc/openvas/openvassd.conf by default.

So I created this file and entered below content to overwrite the default value for Redis Server.
kb_location=/var/run/redis/redis.sock

This fixed my issue.
I have wrote complete tutorial on this site: 
https://waqasahmedkhan.com/openvas-bug-in-kali-linux-2017-3-5/

Comment: It doesn't work. Also your link to the tutorial is dead.

Comment: I have fixed the url. After migration to new server the url stopped working.

Answer (score 0):

comment out “Type=forking” then reinstall openvas
/usr/lib/systemd/system/redis-server.service
[Service]

## Type=forking

it works for me
why comment out
If set to forking, it is expected that the process configured with ExecStart= will call fork() as part of its start-up. The parent process is expected to exit when start-up is complete and all communication channels are set up. The child continues to run as the main daemon process. This is the behavior of traditional UNIX daemons. If this setting is used, it is recommended to also use the PIDFile= option, so that systemd can identify the main process of the daemon. systemd will proceed with starting follow-up units as soon as the parent process exits.

Comment: Can you be a little more explicit on how and where to implement your solution?  Thanks.